# Why it doesn't create a custom post type after form submitting

Tags: custom-post-types, php, forms

I have a form where users can save/update their profile. I'm trying that at the same time they can create a custome post type (channels) with some of the info set on the form.

Here the code:

```
/* mY CHANNEL INFO FORM UPDATE */

function form_update() {

    global $post;
    if( $post->ID == 153) {

        /* Get user info. */
        global $current_user, $wp_roles;
        /* Load the registration file. */
        $error = array();    
        /* If profile was saved, update profile. */
        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

            /* Update user password. */
            if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
                if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )
                    wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
                else
                    $error[] = __('The passwords you entered do not match.  Your password was not updated.', 'profile');
            }

            /* Update user information. */
            if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) )
                wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_url' => esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) ) );
            if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){
                if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )))
                    $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'profile');
                elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->id )
                    $error[] = __('This email is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
                else{
                    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
                }
            }

            if ( !empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) )
                update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first-name'] ) );
            if ( !empty( $_POST['last-name'] ) )
                update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last-name'] ) );
            if ( !empty( $_POST['description'] ) )
                update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'description', esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ) );
            if ( !empty( $_POST['channel_name'] ) )
                if(channel_exists( esc_attr( $_POST['channel_name']  )) != $current_user->id )
                    $error[] = __('This channel is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
                else {
                    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'channel_name', esc_attr( $_POST['channel_name'] ) );   
                }
            if ( !empty( $_POST['pic'] ) )
                update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'pic', esc_attr( $_POST['pic'] ) );    
            if ( !empty( $_POST['description_channel'] ) )
                update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'description_channel', esc_attr( $_POST['description_channel'] ) );
    
            /* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
            /*I am not Author of this Code- i dont know why but it worked for me after changing below line to if ( count($error) == 0 ){ */
            if ( !$error ) {         
                wp_redirect( get_permalink() .'?updated=true' );         
                exit;     
            }
        }


        if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
            exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'form_update'  );
```

**EDITED:**

Changed the first code after first comment. Separated in another function to create post after submit form by users. But still not working:

```
function custom_post () {

    global $post;
    if( $post->ID == 153) {

        /* Get user info. */
        global $current_user, $wp_roles;
        /* Load the registration file. */
        $error = array();    
        /* If profile was saved, update profile. */
        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

            if ( !empty( $_POST['channel_name']) && !empty( $_POST['description_channel']) && !empty( $_POST['pic'] ) )  { 
                // Finally, save/update the channel!
                $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
                $channel_id = get_channel_by_author( $user_id );
                $args     = [
                    'ID'           => $channel_id,
                    'post_title'   => $_POST['channel_name'],
                    'post_name'    => $_POST['channel_name'], // set the slug/permalink
                    'post_content' => $_POST['description_channel'],
                    'post_status'  => 'publish',
                    'post_type'    => 'channels',
                ];
                $post_id  = wp_insert_post( $args );

                // check if we were succesful.
                if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
                    // it didn't work!
                    error_log( $post_id->get_error_message() );
                } else if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
                    // it didn't work!
                    error_log( "post_id is empty/false" );
                }
            }
        }
    }

}        

add_action( 'wp', 'custom_post' );
```

Why it doesn't create custom post channels?

Appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` action is not meant to add PHP code to your page. It is used to add JS scripts.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/

> wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing scripts
> and styles that are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the
> name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.

If you want to handle your post submission, you can use the `init` or `admin_init` actions (if you are on the public website or the admin section). You might need to hook `wp` if you need to access the `global $post` object.

Do you get anything in your error handler? Can you check that you correctly get your posted data with `var_dump($_POST);`?

Does your post type `channels` is registered somewhere, your current user needs to be allowed to create the post type. **You should check the `capabilities` that you set when registering your post type.** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where should I write `var_dump($_POST);` ? If I write it inside the function where will be display it if it doesn't create a custom post type? Sorry, I'm quite newbie...

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I have changed the question. Putting in another function with the hook 'init' for create custom post type after submitting form by users

Comment: I think they do have capabilities as their role is 'instructor' what is the same as 'author'

Comment: And yes. I have channels registered as custom post type. So it is possible to create channels posts. But not from submiting the form

Comment: @Zaesar what does your function `get_channel_by_author` returns? It should be `0` to create a new post, otherwise the post will be updated. Can you try again with the administrator user so we can be sure that it's not a user permission issue?

Comment: The `var_dump($_POST);` should be inside your third `if`just before you try to save your post. If you cannot see the print variable on your screen try to inspect the source code `F12`. If you still cannot see it, probably you never get into your `if` successfully.

Comment: You can also try passing `true` to the `wp_insert_post` method second parameter to return an Error object in case something wrong happened.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I have tested with admin role. But nothing. Aslo added to show error log in function `get_channel_by_author` but I don't get any message on error_log file. Sorry if I just make dumb things. I'm trying to learn by myself and just searching on goolge is a bit confusing... here the link of the whole code [link]https://gist.github.com/venturaEffect/daca393c8baff83c96dbc40b8df7e83f

Comment: https://gist.github.com/venturaEffect/daca393c8baff83c96dbc40b8df7e83f#file-functions-php-L165 the $user_id variable is never instanciated and $user is never used anyway. This means that you probably always get 0 as a result of the get_channel_by_author function on line 166.

If you want to check if the result is an error on line 178, you need to set the second parameter of wp_insert_post($args, true); to true on the line 175. Else it will return false if there is an error. Can you already to that?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not see anything in your `wp_posts` table in your database? Maybe they are created but you can't see them in WP because of some error?

Comment: Appreciate your effort to help me. I've added to true ẁp_insert_post ()` on the functions.php. I also added `var_dump($_POST);` on the thrid if. I've checked with F12, it shows nothing. I went to the database and checked on `ẁp_posts` there are no channels posts created through the form. It appears some posts but they were created as admin and directly. Whothout submiting the form. I have updated the functions.php on github how it looks now... [link]https://gist.github.com/venturaEffect/daca393c8baff83c96dbc40b8df7e83f  Searching also on google.

Comment: I think that for some reason you never reach this point. Else you would either have new posts in your table, or an error. Try to write `die('xxx');` at different points of your code to see until where you really go. (Also added comments on your gist)

Comment: Ok, that's weird. I added `die('xxx');` on `form_update()` and it gives the xxx. But if I put inside the other functions `custom_post ()` , `get_channel_by_author`, `handle_channel_post` and `get_channel_by_slug` it shows nothing . What is confussing to me is that even not `custom_post` what has nearly the same with statements and variables as `form_update` which does show the xxx when adding `die(xxx)`

Comment: Your `add_action('init')` call is at the wrong place. It should be outside of the custom_post function declaration.

Comment: ‍♂️ But after changing it I get `": Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in" "  on line 157"` and it is exactly like the function `form_update`.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. Try using `add_action('wp')` instead of `add_action('init')`

Comment: Thanks @Tim for the update. There is no error message anymore. But still not saving or updating 'channel'

Comment: But how far do you go now, can you see the `die` until the line where you try to insert the post? Did you try to var_dump your $_POST variable to check the content?

Comment: Added `    global $current_user, $wp_roles;  $user_id = get_current_user_id();` on `custom_post ()`, `get_channel_by_author()` and on `handle_channel_post(`. Tested also `die('xxx');` . On `custom_post()` shows the xxx, so it seems now it reads the function. But still doesn't create the 'channel' post. Tested `die('xxx');` on the other functions. It shows nothing.

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're discussing is not the original question. The goal of the answer is to answer the Q, not to solve other related problems.  `Zaesar, you've asked a few questions trying to get this to work but you've never asked how to do it from scratch, and have focused on trying to get your current system fixed. I'd recommend asking how it should be done, rather than how to make what you have work. I don't see how asking it in a new question could hurt. Otherwise there's too many moving parts that aren't mentioned and too little context that's hidden from users trying to answer

Comment: I don't know why, but in n stack overflow as a newbie there are not many options to even make a question right.... So, now. Should I just edit the question and ask how to do something from scratch? Beautiful, thanks @tom, fighting with your help since days

Comment: You have 2 basic questions, 1: how to create a post using a frontend form ( ask the Q, include the code for a basic form, ask how to create a post when the form is submitted, high probability the Q has already been asked and answered ). 2: How to update a post when a user updates their profle ( I believe I answered that for you on another question ). It doesn't make sense to try to fix something if you don't understand the fundamental behind it, so ask about those, and don't turn it into a thread on how to fix your issue, just focus on that specific question, you can always follow it up

Comment: And don't edit questions you've already asked to turn them into brand new questions

Comment: So, I should not make anything because there are already questions of how to do basic frontend form that creates a custom post type. That BTW I think I have read all of them. So, why I came to this situation if there is already questions covered in a basic form? Maybe because it isn't so simple.